# Can includes be singular?

Tags: subjects

Is this a correct usage of the word include?

Your dues includes your membership fee for the season, your Handbook, prize money, and birdie pins. You must maintain your annual GHIN Membership which is currently $15.00.  This must be renewed every year on January 1st at the Pro Shop.

Comment: '[D]ues' is plural only and therefore you write 'include'. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dues '[I]ncludes' is for the singular.

Comment: The question is whether "dues", in this sense, is singular or plural.  As used it refers to a single entity, and this is a common usage.  So it should either be simply "singular", or, that *Get out of jail free* card, "singular, plural in construction".  I'm not sure even prescriptivists are solidly aligned on one side or the other.

Comment: @Hot Licks 'Singular in concept, plural in form, taking plural agreement (usually)'.

Answer (score 2):

After writing includes you can write a single item or multiple items, but the word that is associated with include i.e, the _____ include/includes makes all the difference.

The package INCLUDES a free massage/ a free massage and a pedicure. 
Package = singular, so includes.

The books issued INCLUDE the dictionary/ the dictionary, the biography and the grammer. 
 Books = plural, so include.

It's the same as

He writes. (singular noun)
They write. ( plural noun)